# Error in stored procedure with string return type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Signin_Check] 
    @uid varchar(50), @pwd varchar(50), @uname varchar(50) output
AS
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM threeLayer_user WHERE uid = @uid and pass = @pwd)
   BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      SELECT @uname = name 
      FROM threeLayer_user 
      WHERE uid = @uid and pass = @pwd

      RETURN @uname
   END
```

This stored procedure is throwing an error :

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Saurav' to data type int.*

Comment: what are the datatypes on the table?

Answer (score 6):

Your code contains the line

```
return @uname
```

the return statement can only accept integer values. However, your @uname parameter is an output parameter, so you do not need to also return it. Just make sure that you specify `OUTPUT` when calling the sproc:

```
EXEC dbo.Signin_Check @uid, @password, @uname OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SP doesn't seem to have bad code related to the error, could you check well the parameters being passed to the stored procedure (i.e. their order and their type)? The problem can be the values that you are passing and not the actual procedure.

Could you append to your post the code you are using when you invoke the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's `varchar` column?

```
@uid varchar(50) / int
uid = @uid
```